# Azure resource creation issue - "The subscription is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm"

Tags: azure, resources

I have done the traditional such as affirm my subscription is active and that microsoft.web is registered.  I'm getting the following error when trying to create web app resource, but looks like same issue with any resource.

```
The subscription is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm.
```

I am doing it through the azure portal.  I was expecting that it would successfully deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a transient issue on the Azure
platform, As per the this [**MS Q & A**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1527674/the-subscription-is-not-allowed-to-create-or-updat) suggestion by **VenkateshDodda-MSFT** where the same issue was resolved by the customer by referring the solution below:-

- Retry the deployment of the Web app and the issue will be fixed.
- Log out of your Azure account and Log in again via Incognito Window Chrome or InPrivate Tab Edge, And try the deployment of Fresh Web app again.
- Retry the deployment of the Web App in another region.
- If the issue persists, Raise an [Azure Support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to get this issue resolved from the backend.

***I tried the deployment of the Web app in Australia East region and it was successful:-***

[image]